# Rotate UIBezierPath rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanted to rotate my ellipse but I don't manage to do it.

I tried to make a CGAffineTransform, but my rectangle disappeared and I also tried a to do a CATransformRotate or something like this on note, but didn't managed to use it properly

```
let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 10, height: 15))
    UIColor.gray.setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()

    let rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 3.0))
    ovalPath.apply(rotation)

    let note = CAShapeLayer()
    note.path = ovalPath.cgPath
    note.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    view.layer.addSublayer(note)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're rotating the path off the screen because of the x/y offset in the cgrect (it's rotating around (0,0)). try this and rotate ccw a bit to see the rotation behavior work correctly. If you want the layer to be at coordinate 100,100 you can use another transform to move it:

```
let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 15))
        UIColor.gray.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()

        let rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI / 3.0))
        ovalPath.apply(rotation)

        let note = CAShapeLayer()
        note.path = ovalPath.cgPath
        note.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        view.layer.addSublayer(note)
```